# magento 2 how to set previous order shipping rate in reorder?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have an extension installed for custom shipping rates for backend order creation.

Now there is an issue in that extension. If I create order from backend with custom shipping rate then it works properly and order will be created with added shipping rate, But if I reorder that created order again then it is not prepopulating my previously added custom shipping rate in the latest order. It should be prepopulated.

So how can I make previously selected rates prepopulated in the latest order ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: from admin or frontend reorder?

Comment: @SohelRana from admin reorder.